# Python - concatenate two same columns and leave other unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have some data like

```
>>> df1
  Col1     Col2
0   Hi    Hello
1  How     Fine
2  Why  Because
3  You       Me
4   We     They
>>> df2
      Col1   Col2
0       Mr    Mrs
1  Welcome    Bye
2      Wow    Ohh
3      Sit  Stand
```

I want to concatenate only the first Column `Col1` of these two dataframes and update the `df1` leaving `Col2` unchanged but i am unable to do it

i tried many ways but failed doing this

**Output I want**

```
>>> df2
  Col1     Col2
0   Hi    Hello
1  How     Fine
2  Why  Because
3  You       Me
4  We     They
5  Mr
6  Welcome
7  Wow
8  Sit
```

It doesnt matter if index is different or there comes NaN instead of Empty Cells

**Things i Tried**

**1**

```
>>> r=pd.concat([df1["Col1"],df2["Col1"]])
>>> df1["Col1"] = r.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df1
  Col1     Col2
0   Hi    Hello
1  How     Fine
2  Why  Because
3  You       Me
4   We     They
```

**2**

```
>>> pd.concat([df1["Col1"],df2])
     0     Col1   Col2
0   Hi      NaN    NaN
1  How      NaN    NaN
2  Why      NaN    NaN
3  You      NaN    NaN
4   We      NaN    NaN
0  NaN       Mr    Mrs
1  NaN  Welcome    Bye
2  NaN      Wow    Ohh
3  NaN      Sit  Stand
```

**3**

`I Tried append(), merge() and some more techniques but failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `append`

```
df1.append(df2[['Col1']])

      Col1     Col2
0       Hi    Hello
1      How     Fine
2      Why  Because
3      You       Me
4       We     They
0       Mr      NaN
1  Welcome      NaN
2      Wow      NaN
3      Sit      NaN
```

---

### `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2[['Col1']]])

      Col1     Col2
0       Hi    Hello
1      How     Fine
2      Why  Because
3      You       Me
4       We     They
0       Mr      NaN
1  Welcome      NaN
2      Wow      NaN
3      Sit      NaN
```

---

In either case, you can pass the `ignore_index=True` option to ignore the index.

```
df1.append(df2[['Col1']], ignore_index=True)

      Col1     Col2
0       Hi    Hello
1      How     Fine
2      Why  Because
3      You       Me
4       We     They
5       Mr      NaN
6  Welcome      NaN
7      Wow      NaN
8      Sit      NaN
```